# Can IntelliJ treat a Java text block as syntax such as SQL or XML to assist editing/formatting?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, embedded-language, java-text-blocks

[Java 15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_15) brings us the new [*JEP 378: Text Blocks*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378) feature. This eases working with multi-line strings.

Can [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) be made to parse the text within that block as some kind of syntax? Is there a way for me to tell IntelliJ that a text block is [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) source code or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) data?

If so, can IntelliJ use its code-editing superpowers to assist with colorizing, editing, and formatting the code nested inside my Java via that text block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, text blocks work the same as regular strings in IntelliJ IDEA regarding this functionality. So you can type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, select `Inject language or reference` and choose the language you want to inject. And in all cases where languages like regular expressions are injected automatically into regular string, they are also injected into text blocks.

[image: 2 code blocks with injected sql and xml]

Comment: Correct. Also note that IntelliJ seems to auto-detect a language to inject, with no action needed by the user.